# Uploading files via sails v.9.16

Tags: sails.js, jquery-file-upload, skipper

I am trying to upload a bunch of files to the server with skipper and jquery-file-uploader in sails v.9.x. I also need to add in two other field names with the form and multiple files. But i'm having some trouble getting it to work quite right. When I log the server it says that the files aren't there. Could I get some help?

Here is my front-end js:

```
var filesList = [],
    fileupload = $('#uploader'),
    paramNames = [];
var button = $("button.success.start.uploadbutton");

file_upload = fileupload.fileupload({
  autoUpload: false,
  fileInput: $("input:file"),
}).on("fileuploadadd", function(e, data){
  filesList.push(data.files[0]);
  paramNames.push(e.delegatedEvent.target.name);
});

button.click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = fileupload.serialize();
  var toServer = {
    data: data, files:filesList, paramName: paramNames
  };
  console.log(file_upload.fileupload);
  file_upload.fileupload('send', toServer
  ).success(function(result, textstatus, jqXHR){
    console.log("gettting the file uploaded!");
  });
});
```

and here is the server side:

```
'upload': function (req, res) {

  req.file('files').upload(function (err, files) {
    console.log(files);
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    return res.json({
      message: files.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
      files: files
    });
  });
```

and the express js:

```
module.exports.express = {
    bodyParser: require('skipper')
}
```

Comment: Have you used cURL or Postman to try and upload a file directly, to verify that it's not a problem with the front-end?

Comment: not yet like that, i guess i'll try that. But i console.logged and i do see the files and jquery file uploader is reacting.